# How to export Excel PQ table as a one line csv string?

Tags: excel, csv, export-to-csv, powerquery

I have a table generated by Power Query with multiple lines and rows in an .xlsm file that looks as follows:
[TABLE_EXAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wd0DK.png)

When I export the file to CSV this is what I get:

> Date;Description;Value
> 24.07.2021;VILVIDA;185,13
> 24.07.2021;EGLUOMEDA;599,94
> 24.07.2021;;785,07

Whereas the expected result would look like this(single line with delimiters in between values):

> Date;Description;Value;24.07.2021;VILVIDA;185,13;24.07.2021;EGLUOMEDA;599,94;24.07.2021;;785,07

I have tried "TEXTJOIN", "CONCAT" and "CONCATENATE" to try to get desired output at least inside the excel file itself but most of the time it would turn dates into weird numbers. And I could only do a pair of 3 values at a time.

Is there some easy way to do it that I am missing?

Comment: Seems an odd format for a csv file, but you can, in PQ, Demote the headers; Unpivot ALL the columns; delete the Attribute column; Transpose; Type all columns as Text; merge all the columns with the semicolon delimiter.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld

`Merged(Line break) "Date;Description;Value;24.07.2021;VILVIDA;185,13;24.07.2021;EGLUOMEDA;599,94;24.07.2021;;785,07"(Line break)`
Following your instructions I managed to get to this state. It is a big progress for me but now it adds quotation marks(Presumably because it is considered a string now?)

The other added difficulty for me would be to account for dynamic lines and subsequently rows in Power Query when following this method(PQ would need to be adjusted for each case)

Comment: Don't merge the columns then.  They'll load to Excel with one item in each cell, and all the entries in a single row.

Comment: Wondering why you need this odd format.  They way you show it in your description is a more usual method of constructing CSV files.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld

Oh, actually it might just be my inexperience but I am planning to use the final csv as a raw file from which I would make an array by feeding it into my AHK script and just iterate over 3 elements of this array at a time to paste into my accounting program. But the more usual method as you refer to it concatenates "Value" and "24.07.2021", for instance, when I try to pull it out using ";" as a separator because there is no ";" after "Value" but a line break instead. Maybe I should just solve the problem at this point instead.

Comment: Usually a CSV file has the headers in the first row, and each subsequent row is a row of data. `LF` separates the rows. (Of course, if you are writing a custom script to analyze the csv, you can construct it however you want).  In any event, omitting the Merge step in PQ should result in one entry per cell, all on the same row, which iw what you write that you want.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld
Oh, I see now that it is clearly intended behavior then how Excel does the export. Thanks again for your advice, I think I will manage from here on using the merge omitted PQ output as my input for a script!